# ConEmu reorder splits

Tags: user-interface, conemu, multiplexing

I think this has not been asked before.

Is it possible to reorder split panel areas within a tab group of running apps?  For example; move split panel from top right to bottom left or move half split panel to upper right quarter size.

Ideally this could be done how Visual Studio or Adobe Creative Suite programs do with snapping drag and drop, but I suspect it would take a hot key or macro if possible.

Can this currently be done?  I didn't see it it on the roadmap.  Does anyone know if it is planned or something like it?

Comment: Splits rearrange is not supported yet.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it on the roadmap or in your mind as a possibility?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Tmux has this option, but tmux it self is a bit complicated when you need to scroll back through output history and copy output which is bigger than a few screens. This is tolerable when you get used, but simply drag stroller much easier :). It would be very useful to have "reorganize splits" option in Conemu. Personally i am missing reorganize from horizontal to vertical when i noticed that output is not convenient to look in current splits. I am very looking forward for this option :)
Thanks for perfect irreplaceable tool guys!